# log4j2 configuration is not loaded

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2

Can you help me spotting out the missing step for my configuration?

I'm trying to add logger to my very simple web application: in order to do so I'm using log4j2 (beta9).

I wrote down my `log4j2.xml` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} /%L/[%M] - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="prova.Hello" level="trace" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="servletstest.TestLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and I put it in the WEB-INF folder.

I have then a simple servlet which does the following

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet TestLogger</title>");            
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Servlet TestLogger at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    logger.error("error");
    logger.info("info");
    logger.trace("trace");
    logger.debug("debug");
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

As you can see it is just a try to see if the logger works as expected, but it does not.
By reading here [web app](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) I don't need to configure the web.xml of my application because it runs servlet 3.0, infact if I try to add the configuration I get the following error

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: In a Servlet 3.0+ application, you must not define a log4jServletFilter in web.xml. Log4j 2 defines this for you automatically.
```

But it seems not to load the log4j2 configuration file, since the output I excpect is similar to

```
10:57:55.490 [http-bio-8084-exec-5] ERROR servletstest.TestLogger - error
10:57:55.490 [http-bio-8084-exec-5] INFO servletstest.TestLogger - info
10:57:55.490 [http-bio-8084-exec-5] TRACE servletstest.TestLogger - trace
10:57:55.490 [http-bio-8084-exec-5] DEBUG servletstest.TestLogger - debug
```

instead I get only

```
10:57:55.490 [http-bio-8084-exec-5] ERROR servletstest.TestLogger - error
```

it looks like is not able to load the xml file and it sets by default the logger level to error only.
In the same web page is written

> In Tomcat 7 <7.0.43 you will need to change catalina.properties and remove "log4j*.jar" from the jarsToSkip property. You may need to do something similar on other containers if they skip scanning Log4j JAR files.

so I edited the catalina.properties becasuse I'm running tomcat 7.0.41 and I removed the log4j*.jar from the `jartoskip` property.

What am I doing wrong?

by the way in the web.xml I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>prova</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestLogger</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servletstest.TestLogger</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestLogger</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TestLogger</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

You can notice that `version` is 2.5 and not properly 3.0 is perhaps this affecting me somehow? or jersey configuration?

EDIT:
I tried again and changed the `web.xml` to the following in order to have a web app version of 3.0 but it does not load the configuration.. what am  I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Prova</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Prova</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try putting it in `WEB-INF/classes` instead of `WEB-INF`

Comment: i will try, but can you tell me what's the sense in doing this? i mean web-inf/classes isn't generated at compile time?

Comment: ok this worked, thank you!Anyhow it seems very very strange I don't get the point in putting it there :-\

Comment: It has something to do with class loaders: the Log4J classes are loaded by the classloader, which knows WEB-INF/lib/*.jar and WEB-INF/classes. If you put it in WEB-INF, the classloader cannot find it and Log4j will use the default configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I guessed in the comments, it needs to be put in `WEB-INF/classes`, not `WEB-INF`.

Comment: No, I gave the answer originally.

Comment: @Salandur what's going on here? the first comment is from the author of the answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse ide for developing purpose you can put the log4j2.xml file in src folder.

[image]